# Read from a .txt file and save it in an array.Trouble with fscanf

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault, eof, scanf

I want read from a .txt file which contains english sentences and store them into a character array. Each character by character. I tried but got segmentation fault:11 . I have trouble with fscanf and reading from a file in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<limits.h>
int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("file1.txt","r");
    char c , A[INT_MAX];
    int x;
    while(1)
    {
      fscanf("fp,%c",&c);
      if(c == EOF)
       {break;}
      A[x] = c;
      x++; 
    }
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<x;i++)
     printf("%c",A[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you insert a `NULL` check for `fp` after `fopen`? Also, better to write `int x = 0;`

Comment: `A[INT_MAX]` seems a bit conservative. Is your local stack that large?

Comment: @user3121023 I think you got it right, that should be an answer.

Comment: Better make sure the string is zero-terminated.

Comment: In addition to the advice in the most up-voted comments and my answer, it would be a good idea to change the design to get the length of the file, `malloc` that much space, and `fread` the entire file in one library call. And always check return values, even when it seems like nothing can fail.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: Putting the array onto the stack as `A[INT_MAX]` is bad practice; it allocates an unreasonable amount of space on the stack (and will crash on machines where `INT_MAX` is large relative to the size of memory). Get the file size, then `malloc` space for it.

```
fseek(fp, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);
char *A = malloc((size_t) size); // assumes size_t and long are the same size
if (A == NULL) {
  // handle error
}
```

Problem 2: The `fscanf` is wrong. If you insist on using `fscanf` (which is not a good way to read an entire file; see problem 4), you should change:

```
fscanf("fp,%c",&c);`
```

should be

```
int count = fscanf(fp, "%c",&c);
if (count <= 0)
  break;
```

Problem 3: Your `x` counter is not initialized. If you insist on using `fscanf`, you'd need to initialize it:

```
int x = 0;
```

Problem 4: The `fscanf` is the wrong way to read the entire file. Assuming you've figured out how large the file is (see problem 1), you should read the file with an `fread`, like this:

```
int bytes_read = fread(A, 1, size, fp);
if (bytes_read < size) {
  // something went wrong
}
```

My initial answer, and a good general rule:

You need to check the return value, because your `c` value can never be `EOF`, because `EOF` is an `int` value that doesn't fit into a `char`. (You should always check return values, even when it seems like errors shouldn't happen, but I haven't consistently done that in the code above.)

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/ :

**Return Value**

On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.

If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror). And, if either happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.

If an encoding error happens interpreting wide characters, the function sets errno to EILSEQ.

Comment: This is, by a couple of magnitudes, not the only problem with the original code, and changing just this will not fix the numerous other issues.

Comment: It's one of many problems, and not the one causing the segmentation fault, but it's probably the one least visible to someone who doesn't know how to use a debugger. (It's also one serious problem that hadn't already been mentioned at the time I posted it.)

Comment: OK, now my answer covers everything, not just the problems already addressed in the replies that were present when I answered initially.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should declear till where the program should read data. You can access all characters even if you read line like a string.

try it out

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define INT_MAX 100
int main()
{
 FILE* fp = fopen("file1.txt","r");
 char c , A[INT_MAX];
 int i;
 int x;
 j=0
 while(fscanf(fp,"%s",A[j])!=EOF)
 {
  j++; 
 }
 int i;
 int q;
 for(q=0;q<j;q++)
 { 
  for (i=0;i<strlen(A[q]);i++)
   printf("%c ",A[q][i]);
 printf("\n");
 }
return 0;
}
```